# loopback/listen to Line In, ALSA/Pulseaudio

Tags: linux, audio, microphone, sound-card

I have 2 computers, and one set of headphones. When I used Windows on my desktop PC I could simply select **Listen to** and it would pipe the *Line In* input to the default output device. I don't see a way to do that on Arch Linux.
I looked at alsamixer, but found it too difficult to use.
I tried using pactl module-loopback, but it looped my microphone, probably as it was set as the default in GNOME audio settings and/or pavucontrol
Pavucontrol allowed me to mess with the source of module-loopback, but it only allowed "Analog Stereo Duplex" or "Ellesmere HDMI Audio" as options.
I want to use my microphone for calls, but also have the line in jack be played back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pactl` command (a part of the PulseAudio system) to handle this.

1. First, you need to find out the names of your Line In source and your output sink.

```sh
    pactl list short sources
    pactl list short sinks
```

This will give you a list of all your input and output devices. Look for your Line In device in the sources list and your speakers (or whatever output device you're using) in the sinks list.

2. Once you've got the names of your devices, you can use pactl to connect them together.

```sh
pactl load-module module-loopback source=<your-line-in-source> sink=<your-output-sink>
```

If you want to stop the audio routing, you can unload the loopback module with the following command:

```
pactl unload-module module-loopback
```

It will unload everything by the way, if you have multiple loopback gotta specify the index for it.

Here an example of my system and my devices:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_2f_00.4.3.analog-stereo.6 sink=alsa_output.usb-Kingston_HyperX_Cloud_II_Wireless_000000000001-00.iec958-stereo
```